# Problemas al hacer push en git, archivos muy grandes

Tags: git, git-push

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en unity y estoy usando git para las versiones.
Todo funcionaba bien hasta que iba a hacer un push me salió lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como resolverlo,
espero alguien me pueda explicar
gracias y saludos.

Comment: Es absolutamente necesario subir ese archivo al repo? No puede estar vinculado al proyecto como dependencia y dejarlo en un nexus o similar? Todo el que clone ese repo va a tener que lidiar con la descarga de esas 120MB. Va a quedar en la historia del proyecto, así que siempre van a lidiar con él. Versionar binarios tan grandes es buscar líos que uno no necesita. La [documentación](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota) dice que el límite de 100MB es estricto (hard limit) así que de veras te recomiendo otra estrategia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que *github* (no git, **github**) tiene un límite en el tamaño que puede tener un objeto a la hora de empujar. Ese límite es 100 MBs. Si alguno de los objetos en la historia de la rama que estás tratando de empujar tiene 100 MBs o más, github rechaza el push. Puedes utilizar lfs, como te recomienda el mensaje de github cuando te rechazó *o* puedes reescribir la historia del proyecto para eliminar dicho objeto (u objetos, si son varios) de tal forma que al empujar no haya quejas x parte de github (solo borrar un objeto grande en la punta de la rama que estás empujando no basta si ese mismo objeto está presente en revisiones anteriores de la rama).

Comment: osea que lo recomendable es meter ese archivo al git ignore???

Comment: tu ayuda me sirvió mucho, instale el lfs y realize todo el proceso de nuevo.
y por fin pude.
muchas gracias :D

Comment: Eso no resuelve tu problema. El `.gitignore` no afecta archivos que ya forman parte de la revisión. Si agregas el archivo en el `.gitignore` este punto, eso no va a, automagicamente, eliminar el archivo de la última revisión ni de las revisiones anteriores. Ciertamente va a evitar que los archivos que indiques se agreguen a revisiones _posteriores_ que crees a partir de este momento.... pero tu historia de la rama ya tiene archivos con problema. Tienes que reescribir la historia, usar lfs o simplemente no usar github.

Answer (score 0):

No es un problema de git, pasa que github tiene un limite maximo de subida de 100 MB, puedes usar lfs como te recomiendan o pasarte a un servicio como https://bitbucket.org/ , personalmente uso bitbucket y me resulta mucho mas estable y fiable, saludos!